# Adding a column to the output of `summary(aov)` in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, anova

I was wondering if it might be possible to add a titled column to the output given by `summary(aov)`?

For example, after the following `summary(aov)`, can we add a column titled `aa`:

```
aa = c(4.391098, 12.105541,  0.537330,  6.088639,  1.361073)

# add `aa` above to the right-most column of summary output below:

fit <- summary(aov(yield ~ block + N * P + K, data = npk))
```

I tried the following without success:

```
fit[[2]] <- aa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cbind` to update the extracted `list` element

```
fit[[1]] <- cbind(fit[[1]],aa = c(aa, NA))
```

But, this will remove the `anova` class and it will be a `data.frame`

Comment: @rnorouzian  May needto dig [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/aov.R)

Comment: I think just updating instead of `cbind`ing solves the problem as @Roland showed

Comment: That's fine, I wish that all `NA`s could be removed from your final output?

Comment: @rnorouzian `printCoefmat(fit[[1]], na.print = "")`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print with significance stars, you cannot add the new column as the last column. The last column has to be the p-values:

```
aa = c(4.391098, 12.105541,  0.537330,  6.088639,  1.361073)

# add `aa` above to the right-most column of summary output below:

fit <- summary(aov(yield ~ block + N * P + K, data = npk))

fit[[1]]$aa <- c(aa, NA) 
fit[[1]] <- fit[[1]][c(1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5)]

fit
#            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq     aa F value  Pr(>F)   
#block        5  343.3   68.66  4.391   4.391 0.01295 * 
#N            1  189.3  189.28 12.106  12.106 0.00368 **
#P            1    8.4    8.40  0.537   0.537 0.47564   
#K            1   95.2   95.20  6.089   6.089 0.02711 * 
#N:P          1   21.3   21.28  1.361   1.361 0.26284   
#Residuals   14  218.9   15.64                          
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```